# Can tag filtering find more results?

Tags: feature-request, tags, filtering

Can tag filtering find more results, become a little smarter?

For example, typing:

```
fileext
```

Does **not** return

```
file-extension
```

But when you type

```
file-ext
```

It works.

---

**Edit:** So to solve the above issue all SO has to do is

1. Compare the typed tag vs. the existing tags, WITH hyphens
2. If you don't find anything then also compare WITHOUT hypens

Answer (score 4):

That's a pretty over generalized suggestion that doesn't sound much different than "please make the search algorithm be able to figure out what I'm actually talking about when I provide it **x**"

Are you asking for the algorithm to be tweaked so that all possibilities of "fileext" with hyphens is searched?

- fileext
- f-ileext
- fi-leext
- fil-eext
- file-ext
- filee-xt
- fileex-t

Or are you wanting it to completely ignore hyphens?

Or is there some other method that I am not seeing which would allow text searching to start guessing WTF its searcher is actually wanting to see?

Comment: Exactly. Compare the source text vs. the existing tags, WITH hyphens; if you don't find anything then also compare WITHOUT hypens.

Comment: @Jeremy: Seems pretty reasonable.  The main drawback is having to perform a second search on the condition that the first finds no results.

Answer (score 2):

We already compare both raw and non-hypenated input when searching for tags, but only within the tags drop down (on the question page and the /ask page). I guess we could do it on the tag search page as well.

[Sam Hasler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2541/sam-hasler) suggested that months ago and it was implemented then.

try entering "open-id" (without the quotes) as a tag for a question, to see what I mean.

Comment: Try entering "featurerequest" to see what I mean.